# C++ syntax question

Tags: c++

I need help with a c++ syntax issue I'm having.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RANGE 15.0

#define NUMBINS 15

struct _freq
{

    float ini, end;
    int q;
};

typedef _freq freq;

vector<freq> alphaCutoffSelector(vector<atom> A,string _i,string _j,float r=RANGE,
                                 int b=NUMBINS);

vector<freq> alphaCutoffSelector(vector<atom> A,string _i,string _j,float range,
                                 int bins)
{
    vector<freq> F;
    freq *f;
    double D;

    for (int i=0;i<bins;i++)
    {
      f=new freq;
      f->ini=i*(range/bins);
      f->end=f->ini+range/bins;
      f->q=0;
      F.push_back(*f);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
    {
      for (int j=0;j<A.size();j++)
      {
        for(int k=0;k<bins;k++)
        {
           if(i!=j && A[i].getResName()==_i && 
              A[j].getResName()==_j && A[i].getAtomName()=="CA" &&
              A[j].getAtomName()=="CA")
              {
                   D = (A[j].getX()-A[i].getX())*(A[j].getX()-A[i].getX()) + (A[j].getY()-A[i].getY())*(A[j].getY()-A[i].getY()) + (A[j].getZ()-A[i].getZ())*(A[j].getZ()-A[i].getZ());

                 if (D > (k*range/bins)*(k*range/bins) && D <= ((k+1)*range/bins)*((k+1)*range/bins))
                 {
                    F[k].q=F[k].q+1;
                 }
               }
             }
           }            
        }

        return F;
     }

     vector<freq> C;
     string RN[] = {"ALA","ARG","ASN","ASP","CYS","GLU","GLN","GLY","HIS","ILE","LEU","LYS","MET","PHE","PRO","SER","THR","TRP","TYR","VAL"};

    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++)
    {   
      for (j=0;j<20;j++)
      {
         if (i<=j)
         {
           C=alphaCutoffSelector(atoms,RN[i],RN[j]);
           cout <<RN[i] <<"-" <<RN[j];

           for (int n=0;n<NUMBINS;n++)
           {
             cout <<" " <<C[n].q; 
           }

           cout << endl;
           C.clear();

          }
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Attempts to compile this using g++ -c try.cc result in the following error messages:

> try.cc:1: error: expected constructor,
>   destructor, or type conversion before
>   '<' token.

what should i do??

*[I tried - Ed.]*

Comment: I cleaned up your post.  Please learn to use the formating tools that stack overflow gives you, as well as respecting the community you are asking help from enough to use proper grammar and sentence structure.  I added some better tags for you and made your title express the actual problem (instead of a generic plea for help).

Answer (score 11):

I suspect you should write `std::vector`.  The compiler sees a symbol it doesn't understand (i.e. vector) and tries to treat it as a constructor/destructor/... .

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is not declaring the namespace for the std lib:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: I prefer to just go ahead and use std:: on the front of everything, but he didn't do that either.

Comment: Adding 'using namespace X' is a bit of a crutch for beginners. Polluting the namespace by bringing the while std namespace into global scope is at best overkill and at worst just lazy. Prefix vector with std:: or if you must 'using std::vector'

Comment: @Martin: I agree... but he sounds like a beginner. :)  Its a good thing to point out, though.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are having problem with not including `std namespace`.
You can add  `using namespace std` in it, but
`using namespace std` in header file is not good idea, instead you can do 

`using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;`

and add others as per your need.


Sidenote,
consts are always preferred than define in C++.

so  `const float RANGE = 15.0` is always better than  `#define RANGE 15.0` .

For explanations and many more useful C++ tips, see [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889)

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a using directive (using namespace std;) in a header file.  Also, if you only want to access a single member of `std` then the using directive is probably overkill.  However, in this case the code uses strings, vector and the stream operators.  I think the single using directive is far more sensible than 5+ using declarations.